# Problem with separating UI views from ASP.net Razor using Angular.js routing

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

SOLVED USING DIRECTIVES INSTEAD.

I am trying to separate the UI from my ASP.net Web app which currently uses Razor pages (.cshtml) to present views. I would like the Client side views to be entirely handled by Angular.js using the ng-view directive. I have created a view in StudentForm.html which is a form I would like to inject in my Index.html file so I can re-use it later. However, this is not working as expected and I am getting the following error:

HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - http://localhost:61424/Views/StudentForm.html

1. I've tried moving the file around to a different folder according to my project structure.
2. I have made sure to include the script reference at the bottom of my .html file where I am trying to inject the view.

index.cshtml:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="StudentCtrl">

        <!--The view for the form goes here-->
        <div ng-view></div>

    </div>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/ScriptsNg/Module/sepView.js"></script>
<script src="~/ScriptsNg/Controller/StudentCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="~/ScriptsNg/Service/CrudService.js"></script>
```

my app module: (sepView.js):

```
var sepView = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

sepView.config(function
    ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller:
                'StudentCtrl',
            templateUrl:
                'Views/StudentForm.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

The StudentForm.html just contains the form so I won't include that.

StudentCtrl.js:

```
sepView.controller('StudentCtrl', ['$scope', 'CrudService',
    function ($scope, CrudService) {

        // Base Url 
        var baseUrl = '/api/StudentAPI/';
        $scope.btnText = "Save";
        $scope.studentID = 0;
        $scope.SaveUpdate = function () {
            var student = {
                FirstName: $scope.firstName,
                LastName: $scope.lasttName,
                Email: $scope.email,
                Address: $scope.address,
                StudentID: $scope.studentID
            }
            if ($scope.btnText == "Save") {
                var apiRoute = baseUrl + 'SaveStudent/';
                var saveStudent = CrudService.post(apiRoute, student);
                //Callback to check what kind of response we received:

                saveStudent.then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data != "") {
                        alert("Data Saved Successfully");
                        $scope.GetStudents();
                        $scope.Clear();

                    } else {
                        alert("Some error");
                    }

                }, function (error) {
                    console.log("Error: " + error);
                });
            }
```

CrudService.js:

```
sepView.service('CrudService', function ($http) {

    var urlGet = '';
    this.post = function (apiRoute, Model) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: apiRoute,
            data: Model
        });
        return request;
    }
```

StudentController that returns the view:

```
namespace CRUDOperations.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Student
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult viewAllStudents() {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/naPVX.jpg

This is the project folder structure. I'm having a lot of trouble grasping the leap from using ASP.net routing and views to using Angular.js for routing and views. If anyone could perhaps point me to some articles about this, that might help!

Comment: It's me again :P I feel you're trying to mix two different things, you don't honestly need controllers to return view if you really want routing to be looked after by angularJS. And if you really want to isolate them, why not just use web api template and have a separate AngularJS project (I again encourage you to explore angular). Where you're trying to go with current approach is exactly where we desperately want to move away from in our project ;-) happy to provide you some getting started material if you're open for angular 8 approach :)

Comment: My company actually asked me to learn angular.js because the UI is in angular.js as of now. I am happy to explore Angular 8 though, so please do send that material my way.